# Setting void * pointer equal to an integer

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a question about the following code:

```
int age = 20;
void * pointer;
pointer = alloc(sizeof(int), 0)

pointer = (void*) age;
```

How does it work?

What is the value of `pointer`?

What happens with this piece of code in terms of the line :

`pointer = (void*) age;`

Comment: This doesn't even compile in C++

Comment: @valdo - It's more likely to be 0x14

Comment: @Sean: Definitely not "more" likely.  I'd instead say *equally* likely.

Comment: @Grizzly - The comment's been edited. Initially valdo said 0x20

Comment: Since you have syntax errors and use unknown functions in your code, let's assume it is:

    `#include <memory.h>

    int age = 20;
    void * pointer = calloc(sizeof(int));

    pointer = (void*) age;`

The first part is quite reasonable.  However, the last line casts `age` as a memory address, and binds pointer to memory address `20` (the value inside age).  The address of the memory allocated by `calloc` is lost -- the block is leaked.

Comment: @valdo: Pointer is equal to address 20

Comment: This question is too localized in that it's asking what a specific piece of code is doing.  The [current most upvoted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12038415/50776) is an indication of how localized it is.  If the question can be generalized to be more helpful without invalidating the answer, then I can see it being reopened.  The question isn't too far off from being good enough to be on Stack Overflow and I can see how it can be asked, but it's up to the community to perform the edits to make it into something worth retaining.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code accomplishes exactly nothing.

First, you allocated a pointer for a size of `int`, using non-standard allocation methods.

Then, you assign that pointer to point to the address 0x14, which probably doesn't contain any valid information, and would give you a SEGFAULT if you attempted to dereference it.

Third, you leak the initial memory you `alloc`'d for pointer, which is never a good thing.

Overall, a VERY bad design pattern.

Comment: I imagine his real question is how does this work: `pointer = (void*) age;`

Comment: @ratzip to the computer, a pointer is simply a number, which represents an index in the computer's memory array. So, when you assign a new value to a pointer, as just a number, it makes it so that your pointer then points to the specified address.

Comment: Stop asking people to reopen so you can get a reversal badge.  We do not keep questions open just so people can get badges.  There is massive room for improvement in the question, and if the question is improved, then we can reopen it.

Comment: How did you know the address was `0x14`?

Comment: @0x499602D2 google, my favorite calculator: https://www.google.com/search?q=20+in+hex :)