# what is the void * doing in the following code?

Tags: c, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Setting void * pointer equal to an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12038368/setting-void-pointer-equal-to-an-integer)

My previous question is closed, maybe I did not specify it clearly, may I ask it again?

I have a pointer:

```
void * p;
p = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

then there is a int:

```
int age = 20;
p = (void*)age;
```

my question is how the `p = (void*)age;`works? if p is a pointer, what does (void*)works in front of `age`? and why the value `p` is 20?

Comment: Context: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12038368/setting-void-pointer-equal-to-an-integer

Answer (score 3):

You are creating an automatic variable called `age` and you are also creating a variable called `p` which is a `void *` pointer. This means it is a pointer to something, but you do not know what. You are then assigning the value of `age` to the pointer `p`. In order to satisfy the type system you have to cast it to `void *` by using the `(void *)` syntax in order to say to the compiler "I know what I am doing.".

As for the reason why you are storing an integer in a  `void *` pointer... there is no good reason I can think of. Perhaps you meant `p = &age`, which means `p` points to the variable on the stack.

To answer ratzip's comment:

```
`(void *)age`
```

Means "a `void *` pointer with the value of `age`".

If I wrote `void *p = malloc(1)` then it would allocate some memory  and the numerical value of `p` would be the address in memory, for example `12345`. If I went to that value in memory I would find the memory I allocated. If I write `(void *)age` then I am casting (i.e. taking the value in one type and storing in a different type) and assigning it to `p`. So the value of `p` is 20, `p` points to "memory at address 20". Which is meaningless unless you know that there *is* some memory there that you want to use. I can say with 99.999% certainty that this is not the case. `int` and `pointer` are both numbers, but they are used for very different purposes. One represents a number to the user, one represents a memory address to the computer.

(Of course with virtualised memory the above is not strictly true)

Comment: p is a pointer, void * p means p is a pointer to unknown stuff. but what about (void *)age means? did (void *)means cast age to a pointer?because we are using void * to declair a pointer,right?

Comment: I added to my answer in response to your comment.

Answer (score 1):

The cast makes the compiler assume you know what you're doing, and emit code that converts the integer value in `age` into an address. This isn't typically very hard, since addresses are just integer values anyway.

Of course, *using* the value `20` as an address is very rarely sensible, so this code will likely cause a crash if the pointer is ever dereferenced.

The text `(void *)` is a type name enclosed in parenthesis, this is called a "cast" in C, it serves to convert the type of the expression following it into the named type. Typically, seeing casts that involve `void *` should serve as a warning sign, since they are rarely needed in correct code.

Answer (score 0):

The (void*) is a type cast and is casting the integer value of 20 to a (void*) value of 20.

Basically, you are setting your current (void*) value returned from malloc() to 0x00000014.

If you are trying to set p to the address of the age integer, you need to do this:

```
p = &age;
```

If you want to fill in the memory pointed to by p (that you allocated with malloc) with a value of 20, then you need to do this:

```
*p = age;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you cast and integer to a pointer and then put it in `p` you **explicitly** specify the **address** to which `p`is pointing to be `20`.

Usually, you don't know the explicit addresses of the data you work with and hence initialize your pointers in a program with some not-explicit addresses using `&` operator or some memory management facilities like `malloc`.

However, this use case is very common in embedded systems world. Usually, hardware has a set of registers that are mapped to address space and the constructs like the one below are very common. All these addresses are specified in the HW documentation.

```
#define SOME_DEVICE_REG_ADDRESS 0x10050000
...
uint32_t *p = (uint32_t *)SOME_DEVICE_REG_ADDRESS
```